# Jenkins git credentials work in stage, not in the next one

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following pipelines file:

```
node('git') {
    stage('Set Git Config') {
        sh 'git config --global user.email "jenkins@test.com"'
        sh 'git config --global user.name "jenkins"'
        sh 'git config --global credential.helper cache'
        sh "git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'"
    }
    stage('Set Git Credentials') {
        git credentialsId: 'gitlab1', url: '${GITLAB1_REPO}'
        git credentialsId: 'gitlab2', url: '${GITLAB2_REPO}'
    }
    stage('Synchronize with Gitlab2'){
        sh 'git clone --bare ${GITLAB1_REPO} tfs'
        dir("tfs") {
            //add a remote repository
            sh 'git remote add --mirror=fetch second ${GITLAB2_REPO}'
            // update the local copy from the first repository
            sh 'git fetch origin --tags'

            // update the local copy with the second repository
            sh 'git fetch second --tags'

            // sync back the second repository
            sh 'git push second --all'
            sh 'git push second --tags'
        }
    }
}
```

Stage 1 and Stage 2 work perfectly. Stage 3 fails with permission denied.

I find this strange because on Stage 2, I can already see what the last commit was so it indicates that the credentials do work. Why aren't they working on stage 3?

This is the error I am seeing:

> git clone --bare git@bitbucket.test/test.git tfs Cloning
>   into bare repository 'tfs'... Permission denied (publickey). fatal:
>   Could not read from remote repository.

While in stage 2, I see:

> > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> >     git checkout -f 30f1a7d1b77ef64e1cd44eab11a6ef4541c23b43
> >     git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
> >     git branch -D master # timeout=10
> >     git checkout -b master 30f1a7d1b77ef64e1cd44eab11a6ef4541c23b43 Commit message: "test commit"

Comment: Add a little more information. Which portion you cannot access in stage-3 and more information about error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stage 1 - you add some settings in shell to local git

Stage 2 - you point to actual credentials to be used and use a Jenkins plugin - which would just work

Satge 3 - back to shell, no credentials provided from jenkins, so the context is slave/local jenkins user.

Solution would be to use `withCredentials` for username and password or `sshagent(credentials...)` for private key

```
// credentialsId here is the credentials you have set up in Jenkins for pushing
// to that repository using username and password.
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'git-pass-credentials-ID', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME')]) {
    sh("git tag -a some_tag -m 'Jenkins'")
    sh('git push https://${GIT_USERNAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}@<REPO> --tags')
}

// For SSH private key authentication, try the sshagent step from the SSH Agent plugin.
sshagent (credentials: ['git-ssh-credentials-ID']) {
    sh("git tag -a some_tag -m 'Jenkins'")
    sh('git push <REPO> --tags')
}
```